# PHP - Login via form and grab cookie

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, forms, authentication, cookies

I'm trying to login to the following URL: [pitangui.amazon.com](https://pitangui.amazon.com)

I have tried using cURL as well as libraries like https://barebonescms.com/documentation/ultimate_web_scraper_toolkit/

However, I'm getting the following error using the webscraper via Amazon:

[image: Amazon Error]

This is my PHP code:

```
<?php
    require_once "support/http.php";
    require_once "support/web_browser.php";
    require_once "support/simple_html_dom.php";

    $url = "https://pitangui.amazon.com";
    $web = new WebBrowser(array("extractforms" => true));
    $result = $web->Process($url);

    if (!$result["success"])  echo "Error retrieving URL.  " . $result["error"] . "\n";
    else if ($result["response"]["code"] != 200)  echo "Error retrieving URL.  Server returned:  " . $result["response"]["code"] . " " . $result["response"]["meaning"] . "\n";
    else
    {   

        $form = $result["forms"][0];

        $form->SetFormValue("email", "myemail@gmail.com");
        $form->SetFormValue("password", "mypass");

        $result2 = $form->GenerateFormRequest("signIn");

        $result = $web->Process($result2["url"], "auto", $result2["options"]);

        if (!$result["success"])  echo "Error retrieving URL.  " . $result["error"] . "\n";
        else if ($result["response"]["code"] != 200)  echo "Error retrieving URL.  Server returned:  " . $result["response"]["code"] . " " . $result["response"]["meaning"] . "\n";
        else
        {
            // Do something with the results page here...
            print_r($result);
        }
    }
?>
```

I'm first trying to get the login working, then I will grab the cookie via $_SERVER['Cookie']

Answer (score 0):

add

```
$form->SetFormValue("create","0");
```